# "Over the years/past two years I have learned how to drive fast"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english, present-perfect

"Over the years/past two years I have learned how to drive fast". To be precise, instead of the sentence I need to know whether the word "over" means during or since/for (as in from)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "during".  You started learning to drive fast two years ago.  Now you know how to drive fast.

"Since" is used with a point in time (two years ago), not a period (the past two years).

Comment: If i say"Over the years I have seen different funny movies" so in this sentence "Over" interprets the meaning of "during" and not "since or for"(as in from) . Am i right?

Comment: @Bilal Zafar Yes, you're right. It means "during" there.

Comment: "since or for" doesn't help much, because "for" means during.  "Since" doesn't mean during.

Comment: I think 'over the years' would sound odd to a native speaker for a short period like two years. We tend to use the expression for much longer periods, perhaps decades of one's life. e.g. over the years I have learned that careful driving saves lives, over the years I have lost many friends in road accidents. We usually say, “over the years” when reflecting back on something.

Answer (score 0):

over= during

over the years= during several/some/many years

over past two years= during past two years

Comment: **over past two years** is not idiomatic, nor is **during past two years**. It's **over/during THE past two years** (unless you were saying **over two years ago**.